# What is the homology of the 1, 2 and 3 simplex?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complex

Here is the question I am trying to imagine and solve:

> Compute the homology groups of the $\Delta$-simplex $X$ obtained from $\Delta^n$ by identifying all faces of the same dimension. Thus $X$ has a single $k$-simplex for each $k \leq n.$

I was told by my professor that:

The one simplex has $\mathbb Z$ (in odd dimension) and  $\mathbb Z$ (in even dimension), the two simplex has $\mathbb Z$ (in odd dimension) and 0 and 0 and so on.
The 3 simplex has $\mathbb Z$ (in odd dimension) and 0 and 0 and $\mathbb Z$.
The 4 simplex has $\mathbb Z$ (in odd dimension) and all zeros.
The 5 simplex has $\mathbb Z$ (in odd dimension) and 0,0,0,0 and $\mathbb Z$.
I do not understand what my professor said and how he calculated the 3,4,5 simplices case for example, can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Are you sure the dimensionalities given here are correct? Specifically, when you say "even dimension" and "odd dimension", could you have meant "dimension 0" and "dimension 1"? I'm saying this because as far as I can imagine, the one simplex with 0-faces identified is just a circle, and it doesn't have $\mathbb{Z}$ homology in *all* even or odd dimension.

Comment: Another question is, does your professor specify anything about the orientation used in the identification? At least in the 2-simplex case, there are two possible results depending on the orientation of the edges. One will give you $H_1 = 0$, the other has $H_1 = \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @ElliotYu: I think this is a problem from Hatcher, so it's using $\Delta$-complexes (typo in the problem statement here: "$\Delta$-simplex" -> "$\Delta$-complex"). I think this forces the orientation, resulting in the boundary map $\sigma_k \mapsto \Sigma_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \sigma_{k-1}$ for each $k \leq n$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri You're right! Thank you. I checked OP's post history and found their previous post about this problem and your answer there. Now I'm just going to wait for OP to clarify what they were confused about from the previous answers.

Comment: @ElliotYu I maybe saying things inaccurately, maybe the odd and the even needs to be reversed. the orientation used is the traditional orientation in AT.

Answer (score 2):

By computations in the answers to [Why if $n$ is odd the simplicial homology is $\mathbb Z,$ while if $n$ is even it is $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373137/why-if-n-is-odd-the-simplicial-homology-is-mathbb-z-while-if-n-is-even-i), for example, the chain complex looks like this:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\cdots & \xrightarrow{} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{1} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{0} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{1} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{0} & \mathbb{Z} & \\
& & 4 & & 3 & & 2 & & 1 & & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Of course you need to truncate this: all groups are zero in dimensions $n+1$ and higher if you're considering an $n$-dimensional simplex with the faces identified as in this problem. For example when $n=3$ you just have the chain complex
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\cdots & \to & 0 & \xrightarrow{} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{0} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{1} & \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{0} & \mathbb{Z} & \\
& & 4 & & 3 & & 2 & & 1 & & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now compute homology. The kernel of the identity map (labeled "1" in these diagrams) is 0 while its image is all of $\mathbb{Z}$, and the kernel of the zero map is all of $\mathbb{Z}$ while its image is 0.

This should be enough information to compute the homology groups. What parts are still not clear? Start with $n=0$ (a point, homology should already be known) and then $n=1$ (a circle, as @ElliotYu said, and you should know the homology of a circle, and in any case, you can compute it from the chain complex $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}$), and then $n=2$ (not obviously any familiar space, but use the chain complex), and then $n=3$, until you see the pattern, both in the answer and in how the homology computation works in the chain complex.

Comment: The $n=2$ case is sometimes called a [dunce hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)). Hatcher also mentions this near the beginning of chapter 2, in the section on $\Delta$-complexes.